# What does Selichot consist of?

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, selichot, elul, aseres-yemei-teshuva

In Sephardic tradition Selichot is said from the second day of Elul through to Yom Kippur.  I did not practice all this growing up and am trying to understand now.  What tefilot make up Sephardic Selichot?  Are the same tefilot said everyday?  Does it change day by day?  Please help.

Comment: My recommendation would be to buy an Artscroll selichos and see for yourself what's inside. I don't remember about the selichos in particular, but IME they usually have a good introduction to the prayers of any given prayer book they publish; that may be worth reading.

Comment: @Shokhet Artscroll selichot will not follow minhagei edot hamizrach, thus I'm unsure if it aids the OP.

Comment: Is there a commonly used Sephardi Selichot that you could recommend?

Answer (score 6):

The text of the Selihot appears at [Da`at (Herzog College)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/mizrah/slihot/slihot.htm) and at [Wikitext](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97).

The text is nearly the same every day.  There are additions for the 10 days of repentance, and there is a small section which varies based on the day of the week.

There are also sections which are said in some congregations but not in others.